# Typescript: How to use types of an optional external library

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, typescript-typings

I am trying to use the `Observable` type from *rxjs* as return value of `observe` methods in my own library, but I don't want add the *rxjs* dependency to my project. It is optional and only needed if the user of my library actually uses those particular methods, in which case they would have to install *rxjs* into their project themselves.

I can't find the right typescript syntax though.

The following code summarizes how I am using this now, with a TypeScript error if *rxjs* is not installed in projects using my library: "**Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**"

I've isolated the *Observable* import into a single file, so I can reference it from multiple classes (files) that implement an `observe` method. Also, note that I am using my own type definition files instead of generating them with *tsc* to prevent exposal of private and/or experimental API's in my library.

*types/optional-observable.d.ts*:

```js
export { Observable } from 'rxjs'; // Error if rxjs is not in project, needs fixing
```

*types/data-reference.d.ts*:

```js
import { Observable } from './optional-observable'; 
export class DataReference {
   // many other properties and methods
   
   observe(): Observable<any>
   observe<T>(): Observable<T>
}
```

In the implementation of the optional observables, I use the following code:

*src/optional-observable.ts*:

```js
export function getObservable() {
    try {
        const { Observable } = require('rxjs');
        if (!Observable) { throw new Error('not loaded'); }
        return Observable;
    }
    catch(err) {
        throw new Error(`RxJS Observable could not be loaded. Add it to your project with: npm i rxjs`);
    }
}
```

*src/data-reference.ts*:

```js
import { getObservable } from './optional-observable';
export class DataReference {
   observe() {
      const Observable = getObservable(); // throws if rxjs not installed, which is ok
      return new Observable(observer => {
         // ....
      });
   }
}
```

To summarize:

- I have methods in my library that require *rxjs Observables* to work, but are optional
- If the user of my library uses those methods, they have to add the *rxjs* dependency to their project
- If *rxjs* is installed, autocomplete becomes available for my `observe` methods in the IDE
- If *rxjs* is not installed, there must be no compile time errors.

Answer (score 0):

While typing my question, I realized it might just be possible for the TypeScript compiler to ignore the absense of `rxjs` using a linting style comment to have `tsc` ignore the error. Turns out all I have to do is add `// @ts-ignore` to the line above the export:

*types/optional-observable.d.ts*:

```js
// @ts-ignore: rxjs dependency is optional and only needed when using methods that require them
export { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

The docs at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments state:

> **Suppress errors in .ts files using `// @ts-ignore` comments**
>
> TypeScript 2.6 support suppressing errors in .js files using `// @ts-ignore` comments placed above the offending lines.
>
> A `// @ts-ignore` comment suppresses all errors that originate on the following line. It is recommended practice to have the remainder of the comment following @ts-ignore explain which error is being suppressed.

This fixes my issue. I thought I'd share it anyway for others running into the same issue!